# How to search in string for <span> inside of <a> and unwrap it with PHP

Tags: php, html

What is the best way to reformat the HTML with PHP. Put span tag outside of a tag?

This:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><span style="color:green">Text Link</span></a>
</p>
```

To:

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <span style="color:green"><a href="#" target="_blank">Text Link</a></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Where's the PHP? Or are you asking about how to reformat your HTML using PHP?

Comment: Yes, reformat the HTML using PHP.

Comment: Check out PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. With it, you can load the HTML as a string (or from a file/url) and modify it.

Comment: May I ask what is the point of this? There may be better suited language for this task. For example doing this with Javascript would be much easier (both to code and answer)

Comment: I have thousands of news to reformat the html. For me is more easier to do it with PHP. But if you know how I can do it with JS. Show me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a good use of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function:

```
$str = '<p style="text-align:center">
            <a href="#" target="_blank"><span style="color:green">Text Link</span></a>
        </p>';

if(preg_match('/^(\<p.*?\>).*(\<a.*?\>).*(\<span.*?\>)([0-9a-zA-Z ]*).*$/is', $str, $regs)) 
{
    // $regs = [
    //    0 => ... (original string)
    //    1 => '<p style="text-align:center">',
    //    2 => '<a href="#" target="_blank">',
    //    3 => '<span style="color:green">',
    //    4 => 'Text Link']
    $newStr = $regs[1].$regs[3].$regs[2].$regs[4].'</a></span></p>';
}
```

You may have to change the **[0-9a-zA-Z ]*** in regular expression to match your links format.

If input HTML is multiple line text then you have to use ***s*** modifier after the regular exception, I also used ***i*** as case insensitive just to be sure noone mixed <P> and <p> tag together and so on...

*Note that this if fairly specific solution and for more general solution you should use something like loading HTML into DOM and working with nodes, but this is pretty simple and quick solution for this particular case.*